# Typescript infer passed generic parameter

Tags: typescript, redux, typescript-typings

I am writing redux saga common functions.

```js
interface WithCallback<T> {
  data: T
  onSuccess?: (data: T) => void
  onError?: (error: any) => void
}

function createSaga<
  RequestType,
  RequestPayload
>(...) {
  // ...
}

const saga = createSaga<string, WithCallback<{email: string}>}>(...)
```

When the code is as above, is there any way to infer T among the data of the WithCallback type passed to the RequestPayload parameter among the parameters of the createSaga function?

Or is there a way to declare the WithCallback generic type together using the received RequestPayload type?

### conclusion:

- When defining a redux action, I want to define a callback together
- When applying typing using this, I want to type separately only the payload to be passed to the api layer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the data out of the `WithCallback` using type inference:

```js
// If you know it is a WithCallback and just want to get the inner type
type CallbackData<T extends WithCallback<any>> =
    T extends WithCallback<infer D> ? D : never;

// If you want to unwrap if it is a WithCallback otherwise keep the same type
type CallbackData<T> =
    T extends WithCallback<infer D> ? D : T;
```

I'm not a Redux developer so I don't where you will use it, but it would be like this:

```js
function createSaga<
  RequestType,
  RequestPayload
>(input: RequestType): CallbackData<RequestPayload> {
  const result = {} as RequestPayload; // Get this from somewhere

  // Use the data, call the callbacks, make the world a better place...

  return result.data; // Assuming it will always be a WithCallback, you will need to check that at runtime since you RequestPayload can be any
}
```

Comment: Thank you for providing a clear answer to an ambiguous question.


I respect your insight! :)